# Logging abruptly stops on Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu 16.4.2) AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

I'm logging Python print statements to /var/log/apache2/error.log, but in the past few days I've discovered when I tail the log NOTHING.  Web requests ARE being handled normally.

sudo apachectl restart restores logging to functioning.

At the end of the previous log (error.log.1, which contains proper logging) there is this notice:

**[Wed May 24 18:27:04.070726 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1903:tid 139769062209408] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart**

I understand this notice is probably related to log rotation.  I presently have 52 older logs, but I have plenty of disk space (I'v used 63.7% of 7.74GB).

The odd thing is this started happening when I first used apachectl graceful-stop.  And each time it has happened, the log is rotated, but at that point nothing new goes into the log, until I manually RESTART apache.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a `notice`, most likely related to log rotation. `SIGHUP` is a signal commonly used to trigger a process to close and reopen filehandles to allow logs to be rotated, reload configuration files, etc., even though that wasn't its original purpose: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP ...How is your free disk space looking?

Comment: 63.7% of 7.74GB.

Comment: Well, I guess that's not it. :)

Comment: Maybe https://serverfault.com/q/347731/153161?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot -- doesn't seem like it -- I've never done any log rotation configuration.  I'll see gif it happens again with tonight's log rotation.

Comment: @SMGreenfield most Linux distros (including Ubuntu) have log rotation pre-configured.